# How to set property to false in a Mongoose Schema if _id doesnt exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple Mongoose schema for creating invoices. It looks like so:

```
const invoiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  customer: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Customer'
  }
})
```

The thing is, invoices do not always have a customer. In that instance, how do I only set the `customer` property on the invoice schema if a customer `id` (which I generate before) exists? In other words, if there is no customer information supplied by the front end, how do I set this `customer` prop to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const invoiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    customer: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Customer',
        default: false
    }
})
```

Comment: That doesnt work for me. I'm getting `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "false" at path "customer"`

Comment: What did work for me is setting `default` to `null`, not `false`.